# Writing first order logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

```
I'm trying to write first order logical formulas for the following sentences.
a)There's someone who are not in love with anyone
b)A loves B, but B doesn't love A.
c)Everyone who loves a person, both likes and is in love with this person.
d)Everyone loves B


this's what i come up with:-
a)∃xy¬(Lxy) where L=love
b)L(a,b)⋀ ¬L(b,a)
c)∀Lxy likes(x,y)⋀ inlove(x,y)
d)∀x∃y(Lxy⋀By)


any suggestion?
```

Comment: What is By?  Is not loves and in love the same thing?

Comment: c should have an implies in it.

Answer (score 0):

> a) $∃x~y~¬(Lxy)$ where L=love

You need a quantifier before that first $y$.

> b) $L(a,b)\land ¬L(b,a)$

"A loves B and not B loves A."  Okay.  But $~Lab\wedge \neg Lba~$ is consistent with the above style.

> c)$∀Lxy~\operatorname{likes}(x,y)⋀ \operatorname{inlove}(x,y)$

You cannot put a quantifier before a predicate.  You must quantify the variables and logically connect the predicates.

Also you should abreviate "likes" and "in love" predicates with literals, say, $K$ and $I$.  Just to be consistent.

> d) $∀x∃y~(Lxy\land By)$

You have used the constant $b$ above, so why not use it again?

$\forall x~Lxb$

Answer (score 0):

A.  Some x with for all y, not Lxy.
C.  For all x, (some y with Lxy implies x likes y and x in love with y).
D.  For all x, xLb.